# Best way to parse all inputs

Tags: php, sql

I wanna parse my inputs/outputs based on condition. Now condition is

```
  if ($var == "USD")
    {
    $symbol = '$';
    $customerprice = $symbol.$customerprice;
    $earned = $symbol.$earned;
    $cut = $symbol.$cut;
// etc
    }
```

I'd like to parse this before I insert them into the database, or before I echo them. Now I could modify, if that's possible, column based on preselected condition. If you choose default currency to be EUR, column MUST end with EUR symbol (that way I don't parse anything, I pass values into the column and it ends with EUR) or if default is USD column MUST begin with "$". This might be the best way considering currency is chosen only once, and it will stay that way for good?

Or I could have just a bunch of these ifs? Please keep in mind I'd love to include at least 10 - 20 currencies, so I'm looking for best/fastest way to achieve this. Thanks! 
PS. The above IF would work for default currency being USD, however, if it was EUR, symbol would have to be after the number. I'm just looking for the best way to handle bunch of currencies.

Comment: Kind of hard to understand this question. Or at least where you are NOW with it. I would definitely not store the currency symbol with the amount in the database. No reason not to just give each entry a relation to a currency and process the output after selecting. Even though you have 20 currencies, it's not like this is heavy lifting. Write it in a function and call it before output.

Comment: Why would storing the symbol be bad? That way, I just have to modify the inputs and output whatever I find in the column? I'm just wondering. If I can't force a column to start with $ (without altering my queries) than I might as well parse everything with that function you mentioned =)

Comment: Because the actual number should be a double or float data type. If you store the symbol in that same field it will be a string of some kind. I'm speaking specifically about storing a literal value in one single field: "$4.75", as opposed to 4.75 with a relation to USD currency in another field.